# Using top suit bar elements in custom master page

Tags: branding, 2016, customization

I have got a custom masterpage which I have generated from html.(Sharepoint 2016)

It made the conversion nicely and works ok.

But it still shows the the top suite bar, So I could not find a way to customize the top suite bar as it is rendered in ms-designer-ribbon div which I do not have any control in.

So, I have decided to hide hole top bar and create my own which I can style and customize easily.

But I need the menu items(cog and user name menu) in my custom top bar. But I am not sure how I am going to add those controls to my own top suite bar.

I had a look at snippet gallery, but nothing is there to achieve this.

Could anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint 16, they give more PowerShell control for top suit's bar, I.e changing the logo, text etc

You can follow below URL for SharePoint 2016

[SharePoint 2016 How to Change SuitBar’s Text PowerShell](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34202.sharepoint-2016-how-to-change-suitbars-text-powershell.aspx)

**Concept of Office 365**

You can hide controls from top suit bar whatever you need.

You can follow the instructions mentioned in below URL to hide the controls & combine the suit bar as per your requirement.

[Stack the SharePoint Suite Bar on top of Ribbon – SharePoint Online / Office 365](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2015/09/stack-suite-bar-on-ribbon-sharepoint-online/)

**Note:-**

- This is basically for SharePoint Online / Office 365 but you can follow the same for your SharePoint 2016.
- You need to be sure about the CSS classes from the DOM Explorer of your browser.